# Categorising documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a bunch of ES documents that I'd like to put into "collections". Each document has a unique integer as an ID. Each collection also needs to have a unique integer as an ID.

I need to be able to run queries to get a list of docs in a collection, and easily add an existing doc to a collection.

What would be the most efficient and logical way of approaching this:

- An index of collections, which each has an array of document IDs, or
- For each document have an array of integers (or a single integer) indicating to which collections it belongs?

Thank you.